# how to attach image using v-for in vue 3

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, v-for

im trying to make a set of images using v-for loop, but somehow it doesn't recognise variables inside the tag. pic is broken and alt just shows me {{ item.alt }} thing.
Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="our-technologies__section" v-for="(item, index) in tech_item" :key="index">
        <div class="technologies__logo" @click="activeIndex = index" :class="{active: activeIndex === index}">
            <img src="{{ item.src }}" alt="{{ item.alt }}">
            <p>{{item.title}}</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

And here are script:

```js
export default {
    name: "OurTechnologies",
    data: function () {
        return{
            tech_item: [
                { title: 'Twilio', text: 'gfmds/lgkmlk/f', src: '../../images/twilio.png', alt: 'Twilio' },
                { title: 'Android', text: '12334356676', src: '../../images/android.png', alt: 'Android' },
            ],
            activeIndex: 0,
        } 
    },
}
```

I tried to use `<img :src="item.src" :alt="item.alt">` and its still no results.

Answer (score 1):

In vue cli you should use `require` to load the image :

```
<img :src="require(item.src)" :alt="item.alt"/>
```

Comment: should i add something in code to use require? bc with it page is not loading at all?

Comment: yeah, blank page and console says "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../images/twilio.png'"

Comment: tho, alt is working, and if i replace require(item.src) with actual path it also works. should path be different for require?

Comment: try the absolute one like `src: '@/images/twilio.png'`

Comment: same problem, page is blank with same error... but if i write <img src="../../images/twilio.png" :alt="item.alt"/> it works.

Comment: i added ' ' in the require <img src="require('item.src')" :alt="item.alt"/> and error disappeared, but still, pics are broken...

Comment: what about `{ title: 'Twilio', text: 'gfmds/lgkmlk/f', src: require('../../images/twilio.png'), alt: 'Twilio' }` then in template `<img :src="item.src" :alt="item.alt">`

Answer (score 1):

`<img :src="item.src" :alt="item.alt">` *should work* ™, but then I don't know enough about the environment you have set up. I quickly tried with a fresh project using `vite` and using the `App` component (so that it was root level), it didn't even need `require` for it to work. For this to work your images would be usually be in the `./src/assets/` directory, which they are not and I'm wondering if that's what is causing the problems, that the images are falling out of scope. You likely have a different setup, but I think you might able to use another option.

Place the images into the `./public/images/` folder. This will make them included as part of the bundle whether you're using `dev`/`serve` or `build`. Then reference them as `/images/*.png` without `require` or `import`. As long as you are serving the app at root level so that `/images` resolves correctly this should make it work. Otherwise it may need a bit of extra finessing to target the right directory.